# Como adicionar um item a um listView quando ocorrer evento de clique em um botão?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Galera, quero criar uma lista de Torneios. Onde cada item será adicionado ao clique de um botão criar torneio, seguindo  o padrão: torneio 1, torneio 2, torneio 3 ...

Answer (score 1):

1. Guarde uma referência da List que você vai passar como parâmetro para o adapter. Guarde também a referência para o adapter

   ```
   private final List<Torneio> torneios = new ArrayList<>();
   private MyAdapter adapter;
   ```
2. No evento do click do botão, adicione um elemento na lista e depois peça para o adapter atualizar a lista

   ```
   public void onButtonClick(View v) {
       Torneio torneio = new Torneio("Torneio " + i);
       this.torneios.add(torneio);
       this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```